# Understanding dask profile times

Tags: python, dask

I'm using dask for some heavy workload on climate data. The computation is long mostly because of the data size and because the main (custom) function is slow. I use the performance report as a performance diagnostic but my question also partly applies to the live dashboard.

So here is the summary page of the performance report:

[image: SummaryPerfReport]

And here are two entries in the "Worker Profile (compute)" page (sorry screenshotting was impossible).

- The lowest bar : 4499.25s, 100%
- My custom function : 3911.51s, 86.9%.

Question : How does the 4499s compare to the other times listed in the summary page? Does it mean anything?

Like, 4499 x 9 or x 27 are well under 734405s, so it's not a time "per thread".

(
On a side note, I am suspecting very poor parallelization for this job. It seems the cpu usage stays super low, but that might be because of the machine.
)

Comment: The numbers here do look off. It's difficult to diagnose what happened without the complete performance report or a reproducible example though...

Comment: I completely understand that. The code is quite complex and I do not have the energy to try to write a reproducible example, so I'm ok with keeping a bit of mystery in my work.  
I did think the question about what does each counter count could have an answer without having to see my report, bit it may be more complex than I thought.

Comment: The worker profile contains the aggregate time taken by all workers to perform the specific tasks. Usually, the lowest bar of the worker profile that shows "100%" is quite close to the "compute time" in the summary page. In some rare cases, there is a mild mismatch, but your compute time is wayyy greater than the lowest bar in the worker profile, which is interesting. :/